# Why Visual Paradigm Generates Seq Diagrams from Java without return lines?

Tags: java, uml, sequence-diagram, visual-paradigm

I generate sequence diagrams from java code via reverse engineering but methods with a return value as seen on picture below dont have message return line... Is there a way to fix this or do I have to add the return lines manually?

[image: return line missing]

Comment: I don't know VP but the return message is not necessarily needed since the messages are already marked as synchronous and imply a return.

Comment: @ThomasKilian where is the synchronous mark?

Comment: @Anarkie http://www.uml-diagrams.org/interaction-message.html#synchronous-call

Comment: @ThomasKilian thanks!